# Adding a Hyperlinked text in the array.xml

Tags: android, xml

I was creating list using the array.xml  and populating it into listView
The problem is I need to add a hyperLinked text within the arrayItem decsription so than when I populate it into listView it should link to my website!!!

```
    <string-array name="about_us">
    <item><b>What is it all about ?</b>\n\this is a mobile application </item>
    <item><b>Where all goods go ?</b>Currently the  goods can get delivered only in India.</item>
    <item><b>How will I Know more?</b>Click [HERE] to go to our website</item>
    </string-array>
```

is there any way for doing it straight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<string name="link">1.Click &lt;a href="http://www.google.com"> here &lt;/a> to goto wesite.</string>

textView.setMovementMethod (LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.link)));
```

Comment: I'm not quite getting you! if its with a text box and string I can try this , but how I can do it in an array which contains a lot more text in it ? (text *LINK* more text kind of format)

Comment: can you post some string array with content ?

Comment: I've updated the questoin ..  the main problem is I'm using expandable ListView (customized) for showing the contents ..using an adapter how can I get this ont word linked to web???

Comment: try to set your link as my ans href="yourweblink".

Comment: I've managd to get hyperlinnk by adding anchor tags but click is not working :(

Comment: You were right !! with a little modification I got t right ! wrap my LINK within <a></a> and added this code in java textView.setMovementMethod (LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); :) thanks a lot Haresh Sorry for wasting this much time!!