# Android: how to change text to hyperlink in "fragment"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to change my text into a hyperlink in a fragment. Sadly, most of the websites only showcase text-hyperlink transformation in the "activity", but not in the "fragment".

So far, when I try to run it, it keeps showing "**app has stopped**".

1. I have turned off my **instant run** to avoid possible error(
   [Session 'app': Error Launching activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530648/session-app-error-launching-activity?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)),
   but in vain. And I didn't understand the second method providing in that site(delete .gradle and .idea folder), I don't know where these two folders are, I'm afraid to delete the wrong folder and lose my program...
2. Some say it's the appcompat-v7 problem, but I don't know how to solve it, I try to import android.app.Activity and discard appcompat-v7, but it resulted in a more complex problem.(because all my codes inside are written in appcompat-v7 form)[findViewById() may produce NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671216/findviewbyid-may-produce-nullpointerexception?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
3. my hyperlink code is based on these two sites.[Creating a hyperlink within a textview inside a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403987/creating-a-hyperlink-within-a-textview-inside-a-fragment?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [Adding a Hyperlinked text in the array.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305546/adding-a-hyperlinked-text-in-the-array-xml/24306724#24306724)
   thank you so much in advance for helping me, it means a lot to me><

logcat:

```
04-16 15:21:22.076 6091-6091/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-16 15:21:22.076 6091-6091/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
04-16 15:21:22.149 6091-6091/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent-3/lib/x86
04-16 15:21:22.281 6091-6091/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-16 15:21:22.691 6091-6106/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-16 15:21:22.692 6091-6106/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
04-16 15:21:22.692 6091-6106/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04-16 15:21:22.692 6091-6106/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
04-16 15:21:22.705 6091-6106/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa8e851e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
04-16 15:21:22.710 6091-6106/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa8e851e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8e837e0)
04-16 15:21:22.790 6091-6106/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa8e851e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8e837e0)
04-16 15:21:22.886 6091-6091/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-16 15:21:22.887 6091-6091/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.ellen.spinnercontent, PID: 6091
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.ellen.spinnercontent.FragmentOne.onCreateView(FragmentOne.java:34)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

run:

```
 04/16 14:52:00: Launching app
$ adb push /Users/ellen/Desktop/my-spinner/spinnerContent/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent"
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.ellen.spinnercontent/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet.Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 2682 on device emulator-5554
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from the application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.ellen.spinnercontent-3/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa8e851e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa8e851e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8e83820)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa8e851e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8e83820)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                  --------- beginning of the crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.ellen.spinnercontent, PID: 2682
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.ellen.spinnercontent.FragmentOne.onCreateView(FragmentOne.java:34)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Application terminated.
```

fragment_fragment_one.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    tools:context="com.example.ellen.spinnercontent.FragmentOne">

 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/forone"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

FragmentOne.java:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


       //add this and app keeps stopping 
        TextView tf1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if (tf1 != null) {
            tf1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            String text = "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fd_AtH0yVqU'> here is the video</a>";
            tf1.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
        }


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);


    }
}
```

strings.xml:

```
<resources>
 <string name="forone">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fd_AtH0yVqU">here is the video </a>
    </string>
</resources>
```

build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ellen.spinnercontent"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ellen.spinnercontent">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTENT"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);
TextView tf1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

if (tf1 != null) {
        tf1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fd_AtH0yVqU'>here is the video</a>";
        tf1.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a NullPointerException because you inflate the layout too late. Do this first in your onCreateView

`View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);`

Clarification:

This line

`TextView tf1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

searches for the TextView, but you haven't defined from which layout so it doesn't know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Since

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);
```

creates views needed for your fragment, so the moment you call `getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1)` there is actually no view to find with.

Instead, you should setup things in `onViewCreated()`. Make new function in your fragment like:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView tf1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if (tf1 != null) {
        tf1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fd_AtH0yVqU'> here is the video</a>";
        tf1.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    }
}
```

Also read: [Creating and Using Fragments](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments)

Comment: thank you for your precise explanation and the website link!!! It helps newbie like me a lot><!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
        @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);
         TextView tf1 = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        return rootview;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inflate an layout for FragmentOne where you using getView which returns null view object because there is not view attached.

Update your code with this

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<your_layout>, container, false);
```

Now use v object to find layout views. For eg to find textview from layout use code as

```
TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
```

and return v from method onCreateView of fragment replace default return.

Now to convert text to hyper link then in xml add this code

```
    android:autoLink="email"
```

"email" to others also based on your requirements.